# Linux command line, reverse polish notation

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal

ls /tmp

How can I run the same command but using reverse polish notation?
Is there a mode that would allow me to do this or something similar to that?

I could use xargs but that's a lot more typing:

echo /tmp | xargs ls

This would be ideal:

/tmp ls

or

/tmp | ls

Comment: You will have to write an RPN shell yourself.

Comment: Does RPN even work with functions of variable arity, such as Unix commands?

Comment: There is an actively maintained reverse polish language "RPL/2", inspired by the HP48 calculatiors: http://www.rpl2.fr/anglais.php -- Maybe you can add some functions to use it as a shell? Also, there is "RPL++": https://github.com/NishiOwO/rpl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash (I assume you are using it) is a shell for unixoid systems.
As far as I know, bash doesn't provide such a mode. You could use a different shell that provides this feature. Searching in the web, this was my first result: https://github.com/iconmaster5326/RPOS, but maybe it is far from stable ;)

Alternatively, you can make a command that reverses it's argument list and execute it.
The usage would be like this:

```
reversex /tmp ls
reversex A.txt B.txt cp
```

Here is an example of such a command:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in "$@"
do
    CMDLINE="$i $CMDLINE"
done
$CMDLINE
```

If you name it `/usr/local/bin/reversex` and make it executable, you should be able to use simple reverse commands with the prefix `reversex`. I can not give a warranty that it works. Note that the arguments are parsed twice and have to be escaped twice, too.

Comment: I don't agree that this is a solution to the question, since it does not give "real" reverse polish/ stack oriented unix shell experience.